# Choosing 3 columns for my BigQuery table as a key

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am creating a table from multiple other tables in BigQuery. It's a complicated query. I want to use 3 columns from it as my key. What's the best way to do it for BigQuery ? I am still a novice with it.

There is no primary keys in BigQuery from what I understood. All the columns are stings.

Comment: the concept of primary has nothing to do with BQ per se. The combination of columns can uniquely identified records iin their tables?

Comment: yes, in my case it does uniquely identify the records in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you clarify what you mean by `key` in your original question to help us provide better answers (describing your use case for this key would be especially helpful).

If you're looking to have these columns create some sort of unique constraint, this isn't currently an option in BigQuery—you'll need to handle that within your application logic (or write your queries to use grouping or analytic functions to only pull single copies of rows with duplicates).

If you're looking for joining on multiple columns, you can simply use multiple criteria in `ON` or `USING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  t1
  INNER JOIN
  t2
  USING(col1,col2,col3)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM
  t1
  INNER JOIN
  t2
  ON
    t2.col1 = t1.col_1  --note, unlike USING, these names don't have to match
    AND t2.col2 = t1.col_2
    AND t2.col3 = t1.col_3
```

If the joined table already has this compound key used, you can just use `CONCAT` in the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON
    t2.key = CONCAT(t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3)
```

If you're looking to use this key for grouping, you can similarly just include multiple columns in `GROUP BY`:

```
-- sample data
WITH t1 AS (SELECT * FROM
  UNNEST([
    STRUCT("foo1" AS col1,"bar" AS col2,"baz" AS col3,1 AS val),
    STRUCT("foo1" AS col1,"bar" AS col2,"baz" AS col3,2 AS val),
    STRUCT("foo2" AS col1,"bar" AS col2,"baz" AS col3,3 AS val)
  ]))

SELECT
  col1,col2,col3,SUM(val) AS total
FROM
  t1
GROUP BY
  col1,col2,col3
```

In most other cases I can imagine, just using `CONCAT(t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `CONCAT` to create your a composite key that can uniquely identify your records:

See the following toy example

```
Select 
CONCAT(CAST(v1.numbers as String),v2.fruits,CAST(v3.bools as String)) as key
, v1.numbers
, v2.fruits
, v3.bools
from (SELECT  numbers from unnest([1, 2, 3]) as numbers) v1,
     (Select fruits from unnest(["apple", "pear", "orange"]) as fruits) as v2,
     (SELECT bools from unnest([true, false, true]) as bools)  as v3
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

When I need to introduce kind of key across few columns, I am usually using `TO_JSON_STRING()` function instead of `CONCAT()`

There are at least few reasons:

1. To use CONCAT you need first CAST all involved columns as STRING, while TO_JSON_STRING does not require this
2. simple CONCAT does not really produces correct key in edge cases - for example - for below two different rows - CONCAT will produce same key - `1123`, while TO_JSON_STRING will produce two different keys: `{"x":"11","y":"2","z":"3"}` and `{"x":"1","y":"12","z":"3"}`

   SELECT '11' x, '2' y, '3' z UNION ALL
   SELECT '1', '12', '3'

Comment: you can and `-` to separate columns to avoid the above case

Comment: again you can come up with a delimiter that  makes those edge cases unique. that's the point

Comment: sure. that is why I prefer not to use it for this purpose - to avoid coming with something every time :o) and rather use generic approach